# Map function returning variables with brackets and quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sequel

I'm  trying to use the `pipedrive-ruby` and Sequel gems to retrieve and store data from a JSON hash to a database, but it always returns values with quotes in every cell and square brackets at the beginning and end of the string. How can I solve this?

Code:

```
query_values = activities.map do |activity|
 "#{activity['id']}"
end

query = "INSERT INTO pd_activities (id) VALUES (#{query_values})"
insert_ds = DB[query]
insert_ds.insert
```

This is the error when trying to insert into the database:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:186:in `async_exec': PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "[" (Sequel::DatabaseError)
LINE 1: INSERT INTO pd_activities (id) VALUES (["72943", "73532", "7...
```

Comment: Michael Gaskill already provded the solution; just an explanation, **why** your approach failed: By using string interpolation (`"#{....}"`), the method `to_s`  is silently applied to what is insde the interpolation braces, and `Array#to_s` produces the unwanted brackets.

Comment: To emphasize: do not use interpolation to add the values. Use [the built-in and idiomatic methods](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Inserting+Records) in Sequel to add data. Sequel will do the right thing and you'll be happier you did. ORMs, like Sequel, are pretty powerful creatures these days and it pays to learn them. Don't treat them like a simple driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using string interpolation in an improper way to include values into an SQL statement.

This will work, instead:

```
query = "INSERT INTO pd_activities (id) VALUES ("#{query_values.join(', ')}")"
```

If the values in `activities` are integers, you can avoid string interpolation in the `activities.map` step.  To do this, simply use this:

```
query_values = activities.map {|activity| activity['id'] }
```

If `activities = [12, 34, 98, 142]`, this will produce:

```
"INSERT INTO pd_activities (id) VALUES (12, 34, 98, 142)"
```

However, if the values in `activities` are strings, you should do this instead:

```
query_values = activities.map {|activity| "'#{activity['id']}'" }
```

If `activities = ["12", "34", "98", "142"]`, this will produce:

```
"INSERT INTO pd_activities (id) VALUES ('12', '34', '98', '142')"
```

Comment: Special thanks to @Michal Gaskill, that really worked for me.

Comment: The better path is to take advantage of Sequel's ability to build the query/insert statement: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Inserting+Records